# Add client-side sorting to the find-users page

Tags: feature-request, search, user-accounts

For an example, check out this search:

https://stackoverflow.com/admin/find-users/pradeep

You'll notice that there are *tons* of hits on this.  I've scanned through the list and found a few dupes, but I'm sure there are more.

It would be easier to scan user lists like this if we had client-side sorting.  Being able to sort on each column (name, email, id) would make it much easier to find duplicates in situations like this one, where a user search results in tons of hits.